# Python: xpath + regex with lxml and onclick?

Tags: python, xpath

Suppose I'm looking for all `<a onclick=...>` that call the `String.fromCharCode` javascript code. What's the simplest way to find all of them?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `contains()`:

```
doc.xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "String.fromCharCode")]')
```